# is it possible to run shell command inside the service

Tags: bash, service, systemd, rhel, systemctl

under  `/etc/systemd/system` , we have the service - `cc_check.service`

in the service we activate the script - `/home/cc_start_daemon.sh`

**as the following**

```
ExecStart=/home/cc_start_daemon.sh
```

is it possible inside the service to add a shell command -  `bash /home/second_try.sh`  as

```
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitInterval=5min
StartLimitBurst=4
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitNOFILE=65535
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/cc_start_daemon.sh
bash /home/second_try.sh


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the target is to run another script after - `/home/cc_start_daemon.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not valid SystemD syntax, so I would just make a new script that runs both

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/cc_start_daemon.sh
/home/second_try.sh
```